# Automatically create a copy of email in pst

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rules, pst

In Outlook, emails are manually moved to different folders in inbox (server itself). Is it possible to create a rule to automatically create a copy of email in pst, when the mail is moved manually to a folder on server?

Comment: Move action cannot be detected by Outlook rules. As thims has suggested, you will need to use a macro or an add-in.

Answer (score 0):

No, this it's not possible to create a rule for that. However, you can write the VBA macro or add-in for that.